# How to uninstall a program installed through Wine 

Tags: wine, uninstall, winetricks, google-picasa

I  installed Picasa 3.9 with Wine, but I did not like it, and now I want to delete it.

I tried uninstalling Picasa with the option from Picasa help menu but it didn't work.

How do I fully uninstall Picasa from Wine?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the application you're trying to uninstall doesn't show up when you run `wine uninstaller`, proceed.

---

**Note:** The following command wipes out all the programs installed in the default Wine prefix. Be advised. **Since Windows programs may store data and documents on the "virtual" Windows drive contained in your `.wine` folder, you must make sure any valuable files are saved elsewhere first!**

To completely delete the Wine prefix, run the following command.

```
rm -r ~/.wine
```

The next time you run Wine, it will create a new prefix by itself.

Comment: Note that this remove all files installed by Picasa, but also removes all files of other programs, thus "uninstalling" them.

Answer (score 4):

Removing the .wine folder delete ALL your content. To simply remove one or multiple specific programs, run in a terminal:

```
wine uninstaller
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: When you say _run in a terminal_, what do you mean ?

Comment: Just type this in a terminal. You don't know what is a terminal ?